# Upper Function Input parameter in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to prevent SQL injection in SQL query. I used following code to do it but  unfortunately I faced some problem. The query is not running in oracle DB:

```
strQuery = @"SELECT PASSWORD FROM IBK_USERS where upper(user_id) =upper(:UserPrefix) AND user_suffix=:UserSufix AND STATUS_CODE='1'";
//strQuery = @"SELECT PASSWORD FROM IBK_CO_USERS where user_id = '" + UserPrefix + "' AND user_suffix='" + UserSufix + "' AND STATUS_CODE='1'";

try
{
    ocommand = new OracleCommand();
    if (db.GetConnection().State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        ocommand.CommandText = strQuery;
        ocommand.Connection = db.GetConnection();
        ocommand.Parameters.Add(":UserSufix", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input);
        ocommand.Parameters[":UserSufix"].Value = UserSufix;
        ocommand.Parameters.Add(":UserPrefix", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input);
        ocommand.Parameters[":UserPrefix"].Value = UserPrefix.ToUpper();
        odatareader = ocommand.ExecuteReader();
        odatareader.Read();
        if (odatareader.HasRows)
        {
```

Comment: `not running in oracle DB` - What happens?

Comment: i need set parameter for oracle upper function but it is not working

Comment: There are several levels of *not working*. Does not compile, throws an exception, does not work as expected (in that case describe what you expect and what you get).

Comment: SELECT PASSWORD FROM IBK_USERS where upper(user_id) =upper('" + UserPrefix + "') how to write above query using command parameter to stop sql injection

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters shouldn't contain the semicolon `:`. This is just an indicator in your query that the variable that follows is a parameter, but you don't have to supply that on the .NET side:

```
ocommand.Parameters["UserSufix"] = ...
```

Comment: i try like this but not working  ocommand.Parameters.Add("UserPrefix", OracleDbType.Varchar2,ParameterDirection.Input);
                        ocommand.Parameters["UserPrefix"].Value = UserPrefix;

Comment: And you are really sure the parameters are correct? If you execute this on your database query tool?